# What is the Pythonic Way of Differentiating Between a String and a List?

Tags: python, json, typechecking

For my program I have a lot of places where an object can be either a string or a list containing strings and other similar lists. These are generally read from a JSON file. They both need to be treated differently. Right now, I am just using isinstance, but that does not feel like the most pythonic way of doing it, so does anyone have a better way of doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922774/check-if-input-is-a-list-tuple-of-strings-or-a-single-string

Comment: @mavnn - You're right, and I've voted to close.  The answer is "You're already doing it the Pythonic way." anyway.  :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No need to import modules, `isinstance()`,  `str` and `unicode` (versions before 3 -- there's no `unicode` in 3!) will do the job for you.

### Python 2.x:

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> isinstance(u'', (str, unicode))
True
>>> isinstance('', (str, unicode))
True
>>> isinstance([], (str, unicode))
False

>>> for value in ('snowman', u'☃ ', ['snowman', u'☃ ']):
...     print type(value)
... 
<type 'str'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'list'>
```

### Python 3.x:

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, May 29 2011, 08:00:24) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> isinstance('☃ ', str)
True
>>> isinstance([], str)
False

>>> for value in ('snowman', '☃ ', ['snowman', '☃ ']):
...     print(type(value))
... 
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
```

From [PEP008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Object type comparisons should always use `isinstance()` instead of comparing types directly.

Comment: People should be discouraged from using basestring nowadays because it doesn't exist in Python 3.

Comment: you could emulate this behaviour in Python 3 with `basestring = str`. But that's about it I suppose.

Comment: The second argument to `isinstance` can be a tuple, so this would be better than checking against `basestring`: `isinstance(u'', (str, unicode))`

Comment: Here is the shortest answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26797688/99834 which works for both.

Answer (score 10):

Since Python3 no longer has `unicode` or `basestring`, in this case ( where you are expecting either a list or a string) it's better to test against `list`

```
if isinstance(thing, list):
    # treat as list
else:
    # treat as str/unicode
```

as that is compatible with both Python2 and Python3

Comment: What about if `thing` is a `tuple`, a `dict` or a `set`, etcetera?

Comment: @Johnsyweb, if there was a possibility of other types then the answer would be different. This question says it is either a list or a string

Comment: Dear downvoter, please consider leaving a comment so I can improve my answer

Comment: Typically the object is either a single item or some container of items. It is usually better to test `isinstance(object, item_type)` so the code is not restricted to a single container type.

Answer (score 8):

Another method, using the practice of "It's better to ask forgiveness than permission," duck-typing being generally preferred in Python, you could try to do what you want first, e.g.:

```
try:
    value = v.split(',')[0]
except AttributeError:  # 'list' objects have no split() method
    value = v[0]
```

Comment: Unlike the `isinstance` answers, this approach is better able to generalize to distinguish custom string types from other custom sequence types.

Answer (score 3):

Using `isinstance`:

On Python>=2.3 a string may be a `str` or `unicode` type. To check both cases:

```
if isinstance(a,basestring): # same as isinstance(obj, (str, unicode))
   print "Object is a string"
```

From Python 3 only one string type exists, so instead of `basestring` you should use `str`:

```
if isinstance(a,str):
   print "Object is a string"
```

Answer (score 1):

As I like to keep things simple, here is the shortest form that is compatible with both 2.x and 3.x:

```
# trick for py2/3 compatibility
if 'basestring' not in globals():
   basestring = str

v = "xx"

if isinstance(v, basestring):
   print("is string")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use types module:

```
import types
if type(ls) == types.ListType:
    #your code for list objects here
```

Comment: The preferred way of comparing types is by using `isinstance` or otherwise with the `is` operator. http://docs.python.org/library/types.html

Comment: You can use `type(ls) is list` however that won't work for subclasses of list

Comment: @Lars Wirzenius: No.  That attempts to invoke a comparison of some kind, and while the default comparison for objects of type `type` is to compare object ids, and this results in identical behavior to `is`, it's not guaranteed.  In this case `is` or preferably `isinstance` is the right answer.