# handling python string or list dynamically

Tags: python

numberofrow, 
its value is dynamically set in form field.

now since numberofrow is in multiple tables, 
when i receive that variable from form,

if only one numerofrow, its a String, for ex. numberofrow = 01

if more than one numberofrow, its a list, for ex. numberofrow = [01, 02, 04]

Now how do i differentiate if its a list or string in my python code?

am thinking of using,

```
if type(numberofrow).__name__=='list':
    #do this
else:
    #do this
```

Thanks,
Sunny.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227552/what-is-the-pythonic-way-of-differentiating-between-a-string-and-a-list ?

Answer (score 6):

For this purpose there is a build-in called [isinstance](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance). You can use it to check if an object is an instance of that class (and compared to your solution also super classes are considered in this test).

```
if isinstance(numberofrow, list):
    # do this
else:
    # do that
```

It's quite common to do something like `isinstance(numberofrow, basestring)`. basestring is the super class of both string types in Python 2 - str and unicode - and the test will match both of them.

Alternatively, you can also provide a tuple of possible classes/types like `isinstance(numberofrow, (list, tuple))`. This test will succeed if the instance is either a instance of a list or a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

What framework are you using to get that value from the form?  A sensible one would definitely provide a way to return **always** a list -- specifically, if the value has been entered just once, a one-item list (and possibly, if the value has not been entered at all, an empty list).

For example, with good old [cgi](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html), you'd use the `getlist` method of the `FieldStorage` instance -- `form.getlist('numberofrow')` instead of `form.getvalue('numberofrow')` which behaves as you describe, returning either a string or a list -- and that would solve all your problems much more simply and elegantly!

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you said, but a better way would be:

```
if isinstance(numberofrow, list):
    # do this
else:
    # do that
```

An alternative is to use the object as a string and change behavior when something goes wrong:

```
try:
    validated = numberofrow.isdigit()
except AttributeError:
    # must be a list?
    # do something else
else:
    # must be a string
    # do the string thing
```

If it acts like a string then it doesn't matter if it is a string or not.

Comment: since the code is quite big,
 is it possible, if numberofrow is string convert it into a list, with same variable name, as numberofrow, and then do rest of coding?

Comment: @sunny, that is a good idea.  It's kind of what Alex is talking about with the benefit of the data always being a list.  So, like you said, if it's a string, turn it into a list.  You have be be careful since strings act like lists in many ways (both are sequences and have that interface).

Comment: @ Eric, i got it working this way.
@Alex, am using plone framework.

Thanks all for the solutions.