# Pythonic way to check if a function input is a list or string

Tags: python

I was wondering what the most pythonic way would be to check if a function input is a string or a list. I want the user to be able to enter a list of strings or a string itself.

```
def example(input):

   for string in input:

       #Do something here.
       print(string)
```

Obviously this will work in the input is a list of strings but not if the input is a single string. Would the best thing to do here is add type checking in the function itself?

```
def example(input):

    if isinstance(input,list):
       for string in input:
           print(input)
           #do something with strings
    else:
        print(input)
        #do something with the single string
```

Thanks.

Comment: So what's wrong with your second approach?

Comment: Your second approach seems to be fine.

Comment: The second approach is how I would do it.

Comment: Use cases for polymorphic functions like this can accept different types are rare, but what you're doing is fine

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the second approach, I was just wondering if it is the best style to deal with these kind of problems.

Comment: @ChristianRobinson Indeed, no harm at all. except one thing I mentioned in my answer below. cheeers! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is fine, except that it should do with `print(string_)` and not `print(input)`, if it matters:

```
def example(input):
    if isinstance(input,list):
       for string_ in input:
           print(string_)
           #do something with strings
    else:
        print(input)
        #do something with the single string


example(['2','3','4'])
example('HawasKaPujaari')
```

OUTPUT:

```
2
3
4
HawasKaPujaari
```

Comment: Sorry yeah this is correct it was a typo in my original code. As long as this type checking of the list is considered alright style wise I'm happy enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. However you mentioned the list should be a list of strings:

```
if isinstance(some_object, str):
    ...
elif all(isinstance(item, str) for item in some_object): # check iterable for stringness of all items. Will raise TypeError if some_object is not iterable
    ...
else:
    raise TypeError # or something along that line
```

[Check if input is a list/tuple of strings or a single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922774/check-if-input-is-a-list-tuple-of-strings-or-a-single-string)

Comment: How is this better than OP's second approach ?

Comment: Forgot to tell his code is fine. However he mentioned the list should be a list of strings.

Comment: Should you add this much checking into code?

Comment: This is up to you, if it is necessary for you to check if the list is actually a list of strings yes, definitely. If somehow you're sure it is, it just becomes an almost useless double-check.