# Most frequent values in a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
d = {"a":["MRS","VAL"],"b":"PRS","c":"MRS","d":"NTS"}
```

I would like to create a dictionary which gives the occurence of each values. Basically, it would look like:

```
output = {"MRS":2,"PRS":1,"NTS":1,"VAL":1}
```

Does anyone know how I could do that ? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: The structure of your dictionary is weird. Why are the values not always in lists? This makes it more difficult to handle. `d = {"a":["MRS","VAL"], "b":["PRS"], "c":["MRS"], "d":["NTS"]}` would be preferable.

Answer (score 8):

Since your dict is composed of both strings and lists of strings, you first need to [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/298607) those elements to a common type of string:

```
import collections
d = {"a":["MRS","VAL"],"b":"PRS","c":"MRS","d":"NTS"}

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el

>>> list(flatten(d.values()))
['MRS', 'VAL', 'MRS', 'PRS', 'NTS']
```

Then you can then use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences of each string:

```
>>> collections.Counter(flatten(d.values())) 
Counter({'MRS': 2, 'NTS': 1, 'PRS': 1, 'VAL': 1})
```

Comment: [Link to flatten recipe using hasattr.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577255-flatten-a-list-or-list-of-lists-etc/)  Are there any advantages to checking whether it's a list or tuple instead of just iterable?  The most common thing that your version would exclude would be `set`, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

As already posted you can possibly use `collections.Counter` as it is an obvious approach or else you can either use `itertools.groupby` or a combination of `itertools.groupby` and `collections.Counter`

1. Just `itertools.groupby`

   ```
   >>> from itertools import groupby
   >>> a, b = [list(g) for _,  g in groupby(d.values(), type)]
   >>> {k: len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(a[0] + b))}
   {'NTS': 1, 'VAL': 1, 'PRS': 1, 'MRS': 2}
   ```
2. `itertools.groupby` and `collections.Counter`

   ```
   >>> from itertools import groupby
   >>> a, b = [list(g) for _,  g in groupby(d.values(), type)]
   >>> dict(Counter(a[0] + b))
   {'NTS': 1, 'VAL': 1, 'PRS': 1, 'MRS': 2}
   ```

This Just does the Job for the problem OP has though not robust.

Comment: Nice `groupby` solution.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to map keys to counts - it's essentially a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).

Since your dict is multi-dimensional you'll have to do a little transforming, but if you simply iterate over every value and sub-value in your dict and add it to a `Counter` instance, you'll get what you want.

Here's a first-pass implementation; depending on exactly what `d` will contain you may have to tweak it a bit:

```
counts = Counter()
for elem in d.values():
  if isinstance(obj, Iterable) and not isinstance(elem, types.StringTypes):
    for sub_elem in elem:
      counter.add(sub_elem)
  else:
    counter.add(elem)
```

Notice that we check if `elem` [is an iterable and not a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055360/how-to-tell-a-variable-is-iterable-but-not-a-string).  Python doesn't make distinguishing between strings and collections easy, so if you know `d` will contain only strings and lists (for instance) you can simply do `isinstance(elem, list)` and so on.  If you can't guarantee the values of `d` will all be lists (or tuples, or so on) it's better to explicitly exclude strings.

Also, if `d` could contain recursive keys (e.g. a list containing lists containing strings) this won't be sufficient; you'll likely want to write a recursive function to flatten everything, like dawg's solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am lazy, so I am going to use library functions to get the job done for me:

```
import itertools
import collections

d = {"a": ["MRS", "VAL"], "b": "PRS", "c": "MRS", "d": "NTS"}
values = [[x] if isinstance(x, basestring) else x for x in d.values()]
counter = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(values))
print counter
print counter['MRS']  # Sampling
```

Output:

```
Counter({'MRS': 2, 'NTS': 1, 'PRS': 1, 'VAL': 1})
2
```

At the end, counter acts like the dictionary you want.

### Explanation

Consider this line:

```
values = [[x] if isinstance(x, basestring) else x for x in d.values()]
```

Here, I turned every value in the dictionary `d` into a list to make processing easier. `values` might look something like the following (order might be different, which is fine):

```
# values = [['MRS', 'VAL'], ['MRS'], ['PRS'], ['NTS']]
```

Next, the expression:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(values)
```

returns a generator which flatten the list, conceptually, the list now looks like this:

```
['MRS', 'VAL', 'MRS', 'PRS', 'NTS']
```

Finally, the Counter class takes that list and count, so we ended up with the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, with just built-in function, this way:

```
>>> d = {"a":["MRS","VAL"],"b":"PRS","c":"MRS","d":"NTS"}
>>> 
>>> flat = []
>>> for elem in d.values():
    if isinstance(elem, list):
        for sub_elem in elem:
            flat.append(sub_elem)
    else:
        flat.append(elem)


>>> flat
['MRS', 'VAL', 'MRS', 'PRS', 'NTS']
>>> 
>>> output = {}
>>> 
>>> for item in flat:
    output[item] = flat.count(item)
>>>
>>> output
{'NTS': 1, 'PRS': 1, 'VAL': 1, 'MRS': 2}
```