# How to distinguish strings from other Iterables?

Tags: python, string, iterable

I'm trying to overload my functions by passing a single argument which might be a string or a list of strings. Whats the simplest way to end up with a list of strings?

```
>>> foo
'bar'
>>> bar
['foo', 'bar']

def myfunc(arg):
    listarg = list()
    listarg.extend(arg)
    print listarg

>>> myfunc(bar)
['foo', 'bar']
>>> myfunc(foo)
['b', 'a', 'r']
```

When I pass foo I want to see `['bar']`.

I've fooled around with using `isinstance(arg, str) or isinstance(arg, unicode)` and `isinstance(arg, collections.Iterable)` but am not thrilled about them since the latter doesn't work and the former, well can't I just join to a list or something - I though `str` would do it but then `unicode` came along and am now afraid there might be more of them to test against.

Comment: oh, look, now I find all the dups...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168904/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055360/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836387/
Bit tragic if the best way to search is ask the question and look at the `related`s that it throws up!

Comment: I would ask myself, why `foo` isn't `['bar']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, `str` and `unicode` both derive from `basestring`.

Alas, in Python 3, there is no such common parent class. Here you shoud test for `str` and `bytes`.

---

```
def myfunc(arg):
    listarg = arg if not isinstance(arg, basestring) else [arg]
    print listarg

>>> myfunc(bar)
['foo', 'bar']
>>> myfunc(foo)
['bar']

>>> print sys.version
2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33)
```