# How to make Python treat a variable as a collection (list or set) of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple code as below:

```
for link in links:
    products[link] = get_products(link)
```

I am expecting `links` to be a set of strings. However, sometimes it is a single link and Python seems to break it down to individual characters in the string, which is not what I want. How can I make it treat links as a set of strings even if it is a single string?

Update: Links comes from:

```
def read_from_file(name):
    with open(name, 'r') as file:
        links = file.read()
        links_set = links.split('\n')    
    return links_set
```

And the file contains one link per line.

Comment: Try with `split()`

Comment: How is `links` created? If it really is a set, then it shouldn't iterate over individual letters of its elements, even if it contains only one value. I suspect that whatever code is responsible for creating `links` doesn't consistently return the same type of object every time. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You might find some useful information reading responses to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168904/suppressing-treatment-of-string-as-iterable) for some background on potential workarounds.

Comment: @Kevin. OP's example is plenty complete for the question being asked. The fact that there may be an XY problem here (which I completely agree with), does not alter the completeness of the question.

Comment: @Kevin. But with the last update, I am glad you asked.

Comment: @Jorjani. You are definitely missing something here. The code you just showed will *never* return a set. It won't even return a list, just a string. What are you really doing that gets you a set *sometimes*?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think there was a missing line that I included now. The code now returns a collection (list?). My problem was when there was only one line.

Comment: @Jorjani. Now you have a `list` (always), but not a `set`. How do you get a string *sometimes*?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was treating them as a collection so a set or list doesn't matter for my case. As for the scenario where I get a single string, I'm not sure, which is why I want to find a way to prevent it from breaking down the single string if it is the case.

Comment: @Jorjani. I would recommend making your terminology precise in the future, but aside from that, I believe my answer is pretty complete.

Comment: Noted. And thank you. I had ended up doing a longer version of your answer but I was hoping there would be an even easier answer. I guess Java has made me lazy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `link` can be a `set` or a single `str` element, use `isinstance` to check:

```
for link in {links} if isinstance(links, str) else links:
```

This is a code smell that indicates that the procedure returning `links` is inconsistent and possibly has other issues.

I also don't generally recommend using `isinstance` for anything, since Python is very good with duck-typing. Strings may be the most common exception in my experience, because they are (often inconveniently) iterable. The advantage of checking for `str` is that it is a very special type that is unlikely to be duck typed, while `set`, `list`, `tuple`, etc. are often interchangeable for snippets like the one you show here.

If you don't require a set, you can wrap a single-string `links` in any other container type you like: `[links]`, `(links,)`, etc. I would recommend avoiding `set` since it gets rid of ordering information, while sequence types do not.

Answer (score 1):

If links can be a set or a single string element, use isinstance to check and massage your links into a set (list) before your loop.
For Python 3 check for str type, for Python 2 - basestr,
to be both 2 and 3 compatible I use six package

```
from six import string_types
if isinstance(links, string_types): 
    links = [links] 
for link in links...
```

Remark 1. If your indeed need *set* rather than `list` try `set([link])` or `{link}` instead of `[link]`.

Remark 2. You can go for a one liner with a ternary operator, yet I usually usually go for an assignment, IMHO, more readable and easy to follow when you have a special data cleaning step.

Comment: There is no basestring in Python 3, which OP clearly tagged, and the desired output is a set, not a list.

Comment: I've removed my downvote, but I still think that this is overkill for the particular problem.

Comment: you mean use str instead of string_types?

Comment: or conditional rather than ternary?

Comment: I meant the whole use of `six` in a case that is clearly marked `python-3.x`. Your logic is totally fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: Our answers are the same except for that one detail.

Comment: yup I see, six might be overkill indeed

Answer (score -1):

One simple thing would be to add the following line (assuming that your set of strings is a list of strings):

```
  if type(links) is not list:
      links=[links]
```

This will make sure that your single string is a list (that consists of 1 string)

Comment: This is (a) not a very good way to do it, and (b) OP is looking for a set, not a list.

Comment: You are checking the type with `is` rather than `isinstance`. `is` does not allow for subclasses, for one thing. Also, in this case it would be better to check against the more restrictive type, `str`, rather than `list`, which prevents you from using any other type of sequence or iterable.